# Boot Issue for 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I tried to install ubuntu by bootable pen-drive. When it completed the installation, a restart is needed. But if I restart it, it will resume from the boot menu and automatically open try ubuntu without installing and as a result the installation of the os does not complete properly. What to do?

Comment: Remove the installation USB. Power off the system. Then start, it should boot to Ubuntu on your HDD/ SSD.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

You can just remove your USB installation device after finishing the installation process. And then restart, then it will select your default HDD/SDD by its own.

**Step 2:**
Change your first boot from the boot menu while restarting and select the HDD/SDD.

I prefer the step 1.